# How to get products from all categories but the product A must be from cateogry 1

Tags: mysql

I want to make a sql query to get all the products from all categories. The "product A" exists in more than one cateogries. I want product A only from "Category 1" and the all other products. Here, is my database table.

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   |  category  | product    |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 1          | Product A  | 
|    2 | 2          | Product B  |
|    3 | 3          | Product C  |
|    4 | 4          | Product A  |
|    5 | 5          | Product F  | 
|    6 | 6          | Product D  |
|    7 | 7          | Product A  | 
+------+------------+------------+
```

And the expected resut should be

```
+------+------------+------------+
| id   |  category  | product    |
+------+------------+------------+
|    1 | 1          | Product A  | 
|    2 | 2          | Product B  |
|    3 | 3          | Product C  |
|    4 | 5          | Product F  | 
|    5 | 6          | Product D  |
+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: show the expected  resul please

Comment: Kindly, see the second table. i want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union

```
select category, product 
from my_table 
where product != 'Product A'
union 
select category, product 
from my_table 
where product =  'Product A'
and category = 1;
```

in your case

```
select * from videos 
where trim(submitted ) != 'video_artist' 
union 
select * from videos 
where Trim(submitted) = 'video_artist' 
and category = 1;
```

Comment: Let me try this. Thanks

Comment: show your real data  (a sample) ..because the query is right .. could be the name is not 'video_artist'   .. but you have some white space  .. in have update the asnwer with trim for removing white space ..

Comment: Thankyou for your great support. I accepted your answer.